# how to deploy spring boot project jar in tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat8

I have read some other threads that tomcat uses only war files for deployment. But then Spring tool suite has internal tomcat server which takes jar for deployment. Correct me if I am wrong.

I did google and find out the steps to deploy war file in tomcat but when followed all the steps and calling rest api says 404 not found.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello/{name}")
    String hello(@PathVariable String name) {
        return "Hello, " + name + "!";
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class WarDeploymentApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WarDeploymentApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
     protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
      return application.sources(WarDeploymentApplication.class);
     }
}

buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 10

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}
```

Edit :: I checked all the tomcat logs, application is deployed and unpacked. spring banner is coming in the logs. no error in the logs.
mapping is there in logs. Only when accesssing rest api using url http://localhost:8081/hello/Admin says 404 not found.
The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Thanks

Comment: could you please mention your source which you followed ? The error message is very clear

Comment: Lokesh, I have updated the code. Please check.

Comment: What URL are you using? If you're getting a 404, Tomcat is running.

Comment: localhost:8081/hello/admin. tomcat is listening on 8081 port that i configured.

Comment: i do not have web.xml in project. is it causing the issue?

Comment: What is your goal?  Deploy a WAR on standalone Tomcat or a JAR with embedded Tomcat?  (java -jar should also work with spring-boot WAR files due to the latter's lib-provided folder.)

Comment: I want to deploy jar file on external tomcat. is it possible?

Comment: @Anjali Not Possible .